# If we use a small angle approximation on a compound pendulum, is it accurate to say it exhibits simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I have an experiment where I have to find the damping coefficient of a compound pendulum situated in a clock. It swings at a very low amplitude, so I think I can make a small angle approximation. Because if I assume it has SHM, I can simply use logarithmic decrement to find the coefficient, which would make my work a lot easier. I cannot find much literature on whether a compound pendulum can even display SHM.

[image: Its a very amateur setup, but after all I am a only a highschool student with limited resources]

Comment: yes you can. Please add some details or a sketch of the experimental setup (simple pendulum/double pendulum? hinged?). Then I'll provide you an answer

Comment: It is also called a [physical pendulm](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pendp.html).